# Finding the max id using HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

So I have a HQL Query like so:

```
String query = "from records where lastUpdateTime >=:startDate " +
               "AND lastUpdateTime < :endDate";
```

I need to change it so that I only retreive the latest version of a record between the two dates.

So I have:

```
ID | VERSION | other records | LASTUPDATETIME
```

I need to use a max on the VERSION but my knowledge of HQL is letting me down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need something like that:

```
String query = "from records r where r.lastUpdateTime >=:startDate " +
               "AND r.lastUpdateTime < :endDate AND r.version = (select max(rec.version) from record rec where rec.id = r.id)";
```